# Mulesoft: How can I apply the {header:false} option when getting an Excel file from server

Tags: excel, salesforce, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

In DataWeave when using the readUrl() function, I can utilize the {"header":false} option as shown below to give the column as the key and cell as the value in a JSON object:

```
var myInput = readUrl("classpath://examples/Test.xlsx", "application/xlsx", {"header":false})
```

JSON

```
{
        A: "A1",
        B: "B1",
        C: "",
        D: "",
        E: "E1"
}
```

I'm using a REST API call to Salesforce to retrieve an Excel file.  Is there a way to apply a similar option of `{"header":false}` to be able to provide the content of the Excel file in similar way as JSON above?

Comment: How are you executing the REST API call? Are you using the HTTP Request operation against Salesforce?

Comment: @aled - Yes I'm using a HTTP Request operation to retrieve file from Salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this mule docs references to see supported read properties.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-formats-excel

You can use a transform message and use the same value as shown below

```
   %dw 2.0
input payload application/xlsx header=false
output application/json
---
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the correct data format and properties in the operation or source where the payload is created with the `outputMimeType` attribute. This is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-formats#reader_writer_properties). In this case the operation is the `<http:request>`.

Example:

```xml
<http:request ... outputMimeType="application/csv; header=false">
```